# Installed unneeded dependencies

Tags: dependencies, debian, anaconda

This is my first time using Ubuntu and I was doing well until I made this mistake. I can't tell if it's a big deal.

While installing Anaconda, I accidentally ran this command to install the prerequisites, which is actually for Debian:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6
```

Is running this command on Ubuntu a big deal?

Comment: What where the output of `apt install` command ?

Comment: Please provide release details, requirements can differ between releases, and we need release details to look up actual requirements for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is based on Debian, so it's not a big deal that you ran this command. In fact, although labeled as *Debian* in the [Anaconda Documentation website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/), these are the prerequisites **for all Debian-based distributions** in order to run GUI packages.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and ran a simulation of installing these packages using the `-s` flag in `apt-get` and got the following:

```
$ apt-get -s install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxcomposite1 is already the newest version (1:0.4.5-1).
libxcomposite1 set to manually installed.
libxcursor1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.0-2).
libxcursor1 set to manually installed.
libxi6 is already the newest version (2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1).
libxi6 set to manually installed.
libxrandr2 is already the newest version (2:1.5.2-0ubuntu1).
libxrandr2 set to manually installed.
libxss1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.3-1).
libxss1 set to manually installed.
libxtst6 is already the newest version (2:1.2.3-1).
libxtst6 set to manually installed.
libasound2 is already the newest version (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3).
libasound2 set to manually installed.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libegl1-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libegl1-mesa (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal-updates [amd64])
Inst libgl1-mesa-glx (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal-updates [amd64])
Conf libegl1-mesa (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal-updates [amd64])
Conf libgl1-mesa-glx (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal-updates [amd64])
```

As seen in the above output, most packages were already installed. Only `libegl1-mesa` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` are new packages. The situation would be similar if you use another currently supported Ubuntu release, i.e. 16.04, 18.04 or 20.10.

In conclusion, supposing that you use a supported Ubuntu release, you did nothing wrong and you don't need to worry. You correctly installed the required packages as suggested by Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a list of packages can be installed from the repositories in your software sources simply run `apt policy` on the list of packages. In your case the command to run is:

```
apt policy libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6 libgl1-mesa-glx
```

The results of the above command show the candidates for all of these packages exist in Ubuntu 20.04. Candidates for all of these prerequisite packages also exist in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.